# jQuery load local file not working in Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: jquery, cordova

I'm trying to load a local file via jQuery. My folder structure looks like this:

```
- index.html
- js
---- jquery.js
---- index.js
- views
---- view1.html
```

I have then made a function like this:

```
function loadPage(file){
    $('#page-wrapper').load(file);
}
```

And call it from index.js like this:

```
loadPage('./views/view1.html');
```

This works great in Chrome (when having disabled web security), but it won't load the file on my iPad with Phonegap. In config.xml I have set `<access origin="*" />`, so it *should* work, but it doesn't???

Any ideas?

Comment: try loadPage('views/view1.html');

Comment: Doesn't work either. Loads just fine in Chrome - but doesn't load at all in Phonegap on my iPad.

Comment: If you rename the .ipa to .zip, you should be able to look at the contents inside it - do you see that directory structure mirrored in the ipa, or did it either get missed out or flattened?

Comment: rmc47: Yep, it is the correct folder structure in the ipa!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The status code I get is 0, and using 2.4.0 on iOS 6.1

Comment: Not letting me edit my old comment, but can get external content, just not local. Also using `<access origin="*" />`

Comment: Keverw: Same with me. It's odd! Because it works fine with Chrome locally, if I disable web security.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
$.mobile.changePage('./views/view1.html');
```

Comment: I'm not using jQuery Mobile, and won't do that, since the app don't need it. So $.mobile functions cannot be used (furthermore - it's not a jQMobile view).